# Wrong appsetting.json transformation. Items are not merged, but appended

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration-files, serilog

I have Elastic formatted json for test and production.
For debug I have line based log for readability.

Lets start with **appsettings.json**

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "System": "Error",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.SystemConsoleTheme::Literate, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

**appsettings.Test.json**

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "System": "Error",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Using SlowCheetah in VS2022 I get this transform

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "System": "Error",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.SystemConsoleTheme::Literate, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The argument sections are not merged but added. The end result is that I am not logging json to stdout.

I have also tried to make "Args" the same so I have "theme": null in test.

I know this is not a Serilog problem but me not understand how core merged json configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

Since the sinks list is an array Try to override using the index 0

### appsettings.Test.json

```
"Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": {
      "0": {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch\"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Note : only "WriteTo" is necessary here, since you don't change the other parameters between the 2 configs